# Convert irregular strings to TimeSpan in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, timespan

I have several strings in the format below:

> "1:15"
>   ":45"
>   "1:30:45"

I need them converted to a TimeSpan, but when I TimeSpan.Parse some of them (the first one, for example) it returns it as 1 hour and 15 minutes, where i would want it to be 1 minute and 15 seconds.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You could use an overload of [`TimeSpan.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783407.aspx) that allows you to specify an array of exact [format specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx).

```
var formats = new string[] {@"m\:s", @"\:s", ...};
var timeSpace = TimeSpan.ParseExact(input, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Note that `ParseExact` was introduced in .Net 4

Answer (score 1):

The parameter string needs to be in the specific form specified below:

```
[ws][-]{ d | [d.]hh:mm[:ss[.ff]] }[ws]
```

So "1:15" will be treated as hh:mm. If you are passing 1 min 15 seconds, you need to reformat your parameter string to be `"00:01:15"`. You can simply split your string to corresponding days, hour, min, ss variables and use those to assign your TimeSpan object.

MSDN has good documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx

Comment: Haha that's actually what i need to get out of it... A string like "00:01:15" That's all I needed the timespan for. But this did give me an idea as to how to go about getting this string, so thanks!